# How to sort two array value from lowest to highest and store in database

Tags: laravel

This is my array data from

```
$users = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$bidder = [3, 6, 7, 2];
```

And i want to sort like this

```
users_id   | bidder
---------- ** ----------
   4       |   2
   1       |   3
   2       |   6
   3       |   7
```

and In Controller,using Collections I sort in this way

```
    $users=$request->user_id;
    $bidder=$request->bidder_rate;
    $data = collect($users)->map(function ($user, $key) use ($bidder) {
     return [
       'user_id' => $user,
       'bidder' => $bidder[$key]
     ];
     })->sortBy('bidder');
```

Now when i do dd($data).It worked

```
1 => array:2 [▼
  "user_id" => "2"
  "bidder" => "10"
]
0 => array:2 [▼
  "user_id" => "1"
  "bidder" => "12"
]
2 => array:2 [▼
  "user_id" => "4"
  "bidder" => "15"
]
```

But now i want to save all user_id  and bidder  sorted data in respective field(user_id & bidder) in
array form.So how can i store them

```
   $auction=new Auction();
   $auction->name=$data['auction_name'];
   $auction->user_id=$data['user_id']; //I think i cannot do like this
   $auction->bidder=$data['bidder'];
```

Comment: since it's an array, use a loop to iterate through the array and store it.

Comment: @OMiShah like how ?

Comment: first, you need to have a JSON column type for ``user_id`` and ``bidder`` so that you can store array values in a single column. Or you need to store each single ids individually as rows in your database.

Comment: What kind of column is it right now?

Comment: Right now 
i data will be stored in this way 
["12","10","15"]

Comment: @OMiShah so i need to store bother user_id and bidder in this way after it sorted so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this

  $auction=new Auction();
 $auction->name=collect($data)->pluck("user_id");
 $auction->user_id=collect($data)->pluck("bidder");
 $auction->bidder=$data['bidder'];
```